# \verbatiminput causes the rest of the code to be orange in the editor

Tags: texmaker, verbatim

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FEFF}{}

\usepackage{verbatim, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{R1.txt}

This text is ORANGE\\
$\text{so is this}$
\begin{align*}
and that
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Im using Texmaker 3.5.2, and as soon as I have typed \verba the behaviour begins, but everything still compiles correctly.

The coloring is correct on this site though. Am I doing something bad/how do I get the normal highlight colors to reappear?!

Comment: Probably a bug in the editor, might want to check the editors homepage/forum

Comment: Definitely a bug of Texmaker; the bad coloring disappears if you use `\verbatiminput{R1.txt}%a` so the “colorizer” sees the terminator `a` and resumes correct coloring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax colorizing instructions are at fault here; the syntax of `\verb` allows any character to be used as delimiter, even `a`, but of course

```
\verba{@- \zz}a
```

would be illegal, because TeX would parse `\verba` as a single control sequence, so one of the two following calls would be correct

```
\verb a{@- \zz}a
\verb*a{@- \zz}a
```

(with different results, because the latter would print a space marker). The bad behavior is also in version 4.4.1.

I couldn't find where Texmaker stores the rules for syntax highlighting, but the regular expression it uses for `\verb` is clearly wrong. For instance, it would not stop coloring everything orange after

```
\verb |x|
```

which is perfectly legal code. I suggest you make a bug report; in the meantime you can work around the bug by typing

```
\verbatiminput{R1.txt}%a
```

(or by changing editor, of course).

[image]